# Convert UIFont to CTFontRef and add italic on Retina display

Tags: ios, core-text, retina-display

I have a custom subclass of `UILabel` which makes custom drawing using CoreText.
I used to draw my strings using the `UIFont` that is set on the label accessing it using the font property. I also add some traits to the font. Here is what it looks like:

```
UIFont* font = [self font];
CTFontRef ref = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)[font name], [font pointSize], NULL);
CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(ref, [font pointSize], NULL, kCTFontItalicTrait, kCTFontItalicTrait);
```

This used to work fine until the new ipad appeared with its retina display. When I perform the `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits` call, it produces a nil return value. I found out `[font name]` returns ".HelveticaNeueUI" on these new devices. The `CTFontCreateWithName` seems to work fine with this private font name, but `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits` doesn't. Yet if I create an italic font using `[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[font pointSize]]` it creates an italic font for which `[font name]` still returns ".HelveticaNeueUI".

How should I convert my `UIFont` to `CTFontRef` so that I can still apply new traits to my `CTFontRef` on both retina and non-retina displays?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A bit old but for whomever it might still concern:

That happens because the new Neue Helvetica system font used in new retina devices (iPhone 4, iPad) doesn't have an italic version. Not every font has a bold and/or italic variant.
So, if you need italic text, you need to use a different font, for example, the old Helvetica.

```
CTFontRef ref = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Helvetica", 12, NULL);
CTFontRef italicFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(ref, 12, NULL, kCTFontItalicTrait, kCTFontItalicTrait);
```

Comment: Ha. Welcome to Core Text.

Answer (score 3):

Converting UIFont/NSFont to CTFontRef is very simple if you use ARC.

UIFont:

```
UIFont *uiFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10];
CTFontRef ctFont = (__bridge CTFontRef)uiFont;
```

NSFont:

```
NSFont *nsFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10];
CTFontRef ctFont = (__bridge CTFontRef)nsFont;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way,convert uifont to CTFontRef

```
UIFont *uiFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10];
CTFontRef ctFont = (__bridge CTFontRef)uiFont;
```

Do we need release the `ctFont`？